# Let $X$ be a finite set with cardinality, $n$. Find the cardinailty of $\mathbb{P}(X)$. Show it holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Let $X$ be a finite set with cardinality, $n$. Find the cardinailty of $\mathbb{P}(X)$. Show it holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose we have the set $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n\}$, Therefore $|X| = n$. From this it follows that the powerset $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is $\{ \emptyset, \{x_1\}, \{x_2\} \{x_3\}, ... , \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n\} \}$. We can conclude $|\mathbb{P}(X)| = 2^n$ where $n$ is the cardinality of $X$.

Beyond this, I'm not sure how to show it holds for all $n\geq 0$. I can show it informally, as follows,

$$X = \{\}, \mathbb{P}(X) = \{\emptyset\} \implies |X| = 0, |\mathbb{P}(X)| = 2^0 = 1$$

$$X = \{x_1\}, \mathbb{P}(X) = \{\emptyset, \{x_1\} \}\implies |X| = 1,  |\mathbb{P}(X)| = 2^1 = 2$$

$$X = \{x_1, x_2\},\mathbb{P}(X) = \{\emptyset, \{x_1\}, \{x_2\}, \{x_1, x_2\}\} \implies |X| = 2, |\mathbb{P}(X)| = 2^2 = 4$$

Not really sure if the 'informal' proof suffices or not, but what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tag you have is **proof-writing** I would recommend that you prove your guess - which is correct, i.e., that the power set on $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements - by using mathematical induction.

Here is a formalization of the proposition:

> $P(n):$ If a set has $n$ elements, then its power set has $2^n$ elements.

You have included in the OP a proof of the base case, i.e., of $P(1)$.

Next, suppose that $P(k)$ holds for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This is the **inductive hypothesis**. Can you now prove, using the inductive hypothesis, that the statement holds for a set with $k+1$ elements? That is, can you prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$?

(**Hint:** For the subsets of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_k, a_{k+1}\}$ consider how many subsets *contain* $a_{k+1}$ and how many do *not* contain $a_{k+1}$; this can combine with the inductive hypothesis to complete the proof.)

Alternatively, you can find proofs of this statement by googling or searching MSE; it is a common question, and your question would probably be closed if you asked only for a proof (rather than for proof verification).

As a last remark, there is a direct proof that proceeds somewhat differently from the inductive approach: Every subset can be formed by deciding, for each of the $n$ elements, whether to include or exclude it; this gives two choices (include versus exclude) for each of the $n$ elements, so a total of $2^n$ possibilities (where, e.g., "all include" returns the parent set, and "all exclude" returns the empty set) for how many subsets can be formed, i.e., the power set has $2^n$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let  order all elements of $X$ in any way,  say $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$  and assign to any subset $A$  of $X$ an ordered bit  vector $[A]=[a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n]$  where 
$$a_i=\begin{cases}
1, \text{if $x_i \in A$},\\
0, \text{if $x_i \notin A$}.
\end{cases}
$$
It is clear, by  combinatorial product rule, that there  are exactly $2^n$ such vectors thus $|\mathbb{P}(X)| = 2^n.$